# Windows: how do I run time in NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cygwin

If I was using Linux, I would know how to answer this question (I think). I would just do something like this in my package.json as a script:

```
time ls
```

But I'm on Windows and I'm running NPM in cygwin. When I try to run this command the output is:

```
The system cannot accept the time entered.
Enter the new time:
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. If I remove `time` from the script, or type `time ls` in my cygwin terminal, it behaves as expected. If I type `type time`  in my terminal, it says `time is a shell keyword` if I make my script run that, it errors saying: `The system cannot find the file specified.` I suspect this is related to the error but I don't understand why am getting it.

How do I run `time` in npm?

Comment: @CherryDT that should be my question even when it is working as expected under cygwin? The only situation it is not working in is if I use npm in cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

as there is no `npm` in Cygwin, you are a clearly using a thrird part tool.
I assume you are using a standard CMD as command interpreter
as for Bash you will have

```
$ time ls
bin      doc        Downloads    foo   Music     Public     Videos
Desktop  Documents  figure3.jpg  lftp  Pictures  Templates  Xdefaults

real    0m0.564s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.030s
```

while yours

```
The system cannot accept the time entered.
Enter the new time:
```

is equivalent to my CMD (german) output

```
C:\Users\Marco>time ls
Eingegebene Zeit kann nicht übernommen werden.
Geben Sie die neue Zeit ein:
```

bash shell

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

from `info bash`

```
3.2.2 Pipelines
---------------

A 'pipeline' is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators '|' or '|&'.

   The format for a pipeline is
     [time [-p]] [!] COMMAND1 [ | or |& COMMAND2 ] ...

The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to the input of the next command.  That is, each command reads the previous command's output.  This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command.

   If '|&' is used, COMMAND1's standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to COMMAND2's standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for '2>&1 |'.  This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

   The reserved word 'time' causes timing statistics to be printed for the pipeline once it finishes.  The statistics currently consist of elapsed (wall-clock) time and user and system time consumed by the command's execution.  The '-p' option changes the output format to that specified by POSIX.  When the shell is in POSIX mode (*note Bash POSIX Mode::), it does not recognize 'time' as a reserved word if the next token begins with a '-'.  The 'TIMEFORMAT' variable may be set to a
```

So try to run your script from a Cygwin bash shell. Usually it is the default in Cygwin terminal

Comment: `So try to run your script from a Cygwin bash shell. Usually it is the default in Cygwin terminal` how do I do that?

Comment: Have you installed Cygwin ? The Cygwin Terminal should be available in the Start Menu

Comment: I'm way past that. I think you think my question is much more fundamental than it is. Look at my 2nd sentence.

Comment: `I assume you are using a standard CMD as command interpreter `incorrect. I am using cygwin to run npm.